# How to create smooth png for uitabbaritem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, photoshop, uitabbaritem

When I create png in Photoshop with parameters 30x30pxl, clear background with white lines it looks like poor resolution. link to snapshot of presenting tabbaritem: http://yadi.sk/d/9zrBjrjxBFyva

I want smooth lines in this picture. What way I can get it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a non-retina image on a retina device. Create a 60x60 version and name the same as the 30x30 version with the suffix `@2x`(for example, `clock@2x.png`). Add this to your project.

**Edit:** The graphics you're producing in Photoshop are pixelated, and in the case of the @2x image, very blurry. Since the source images are poor quality, there's no way iOS can magically make them smooth.

Use the shape tool in Photoshop to create crisp, sharp shape paths. Make sure to align the shapes to pixel boundaries for extra crispness.

Comment: if I create 60x60 resolution than it looks like this http://yadi.sk/d/eyykQ2XIBG5Yb

Comment: file name ends with @2x.png

Comment: Can you show us both the 30x30 and 60x60 icons? The raw icons, not screenshots of the tab bar.

Comment: neilco, thanks, but I used shape tool. Circle on the picture was made with ellipse tool. I set shading in 4pxls or about so. The result You have seen=(

Comment: and how can I use @2x.png? may be the problem is that I set image in storyboard but not in code? Can it cause unscalable image like in second screenshot?